# Como filtrar somente números com 'Like' SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select, where, operador-like

Possuo uma tabela em que o campo **mainUnitId** possui os seguintes dados:

- Ad23
- Ad7
- Ad11
- Ad9
- Adv1
- Adv14
- Adv21

Preciso trazer na busca apenas os que tenham **Ad + números depois**

**Meu código**:

SELECT * FROM lesson L
WHERE L.mainUnitId like 'Ad__';

**Retorno esperado**:

- Ad23
- Ad7
- Ad11
- Ad9

Obrigado!

Comment: só usar "%" no lugar do "_":  `like 'Ad%'`

Comment: Olá. Nesse caso ele irá trazer todos os valores  (Adv1,Adv14 e Adv21). Eu preciso que a consulta retorne somente ( Ad23, Ad7, Ad11 e Ad9). Só os que começam com "Ad" e tem algum número depois.

Comment: então vai ter de escrever uma regular expression para isso

Answer (score 2):

É possível utilizar a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM lesson L WHERE L.mainUnitId like 'Ad[0-9]%';
```

Utilizando uma expressão regular em que após os caracteres **Ad** seja encontrado um caractere numérico (de 0 a 9) e ao fim o operador `%` aceitando qualquer caractere após este número.

Answer (score 0):

O métódo like você pode usar o operador "%" tanto como sufixo ou prefixo de uma string.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM lesson L WHERE L.mainUnitId like 'Ad%';
```

OU

```
SELECT * FROM lesson L WHERE L.mainUnitId like '%23';
```

OU ambos

```
SELECT * FROM lesson L WHERE L.mainUnitId like '%d%';
```

O underscore "_" que é o você esta tentando fazer só gira entorno de um caracter.

Exemplo

```
SELECT * FROM ENTIDADES WHERE NOME_ENTIDADE like 'MAR_OS';
```

Resultado:

```
1 | Marcos
```

Comment: Olá. Nesse caso ele irá trazer todos os valores  (Adv1,Adv14 e Adv21). Eu preciso que a consulta retorne somente ( Ad23, Ad7, Ad11 e Ad9). Só os que começam com "Ad" e tem algum número depois. Caso eu utilize like 'Ad%'  os valores com Adv serão retornados também

Comment: Use o inverso, WHERE L.mainUnitId NOT LIKE 'Adv%'.

Answer (score 0):

**Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira**:

SELECT * FROM lesson L
WHERE L.mainUnitId  REGEXP 'Ad[0-9]';